Why do many shuls not have plag mincha/maariv on fast days?
Many shuls have mincha/maariv minyanim at plag most weekdays in the summer.  However, they typically don't at the end of a fast day.  They might have a 2:00 mincha, but they don't have mincha right before plag and maariv right after.
Why not?  I'd think it would be convenient for some people (especially those who have both little kids who are not fasting and young teenagers who are) to be home with that much extra time before the end of the fast.  And if you're feeling sick, it might be better to daven at the earliest possible time before you feel worse.
Are there halachic reasons* not to have these minyanim?  Or sociological reasons?  Or maybe I'm just looking at the wrong shuls and just wrong about the lack of minyanim?

* reasons relevant specifically to fast days - I'm excluding the reasons not to say birchos krias shema before night, because these are shuls that have a plag mincha/maariv on other weekdays.  I'd be ok in principle with an answer that we're more machmir because it's a day dedicated to teshuva, but I'm skeptical that that's the reason, because there are plag minyanim during the aseres yemei teshuva - just not on Tzom Gedalya.

I know of very very few shuls that have weekday plag minyanim ever.

Maybe ask the shul rabbi/gabbai? (Why isn't it rabbai/gabbi?)

@DoubleAA asking the real questions. Maybe because גבאי has an aleph but רבי doesn't.

maybe there's a concern people will mistakenly think the fast is over when Ma'ariv is davened

@J.W. that applies to minyan just after sunset as well

@DoubleAA:  you are right, though with ma'ariv after sunset, by the time I finish davening, get home, and get ready for dinner, the fast is usually just about over
